# phpunit dependency StackTest on netbean 8.0.1

Tags: dependencies, phpunit

I am new to use phpunit. I run a test on Netbeans 8.0.1. The the code is Example 2.2 on the page of https://phpunit.de/manual/4.3/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html. I got an error message : "StackTest::testPop()
Argument 1 passed to StackTest::testPop() must be an array, null given."
I have no idea why there is the error. Do I need to type additional code or something else? 
Thanks for your response, in advance.

Following is the code:

class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase {

```
public function testEmpty() {
    $stack = array();
    $this->assertEmpty($stack);

    return $stack;
}

/**
 *  @depends testEmpty
 */
public function testPush(array $stack) {
    array_push($stack, 'foo');
    $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($stack);
}

 /**
 *  @depends testPush
 */
public function testPop(array $stack) {
    $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
    $this->assertEmpty($stack);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. There is no error on the original source.

```
/**
 *  @depends testEmpty
 */
public function testPush(array $stack) {
    array_push($stack, 'foo');
    $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($stack);

    return $stack; // I omitted this line;
}
```